# Error this.s3.listBuckets is not a function

Tags: nestjs, aws-sdk

I need to store images in S3 in a project with nestjs, and I need to test the connection with S3, for this I decided to consult the list of buckets.

Import the AWS module as follows on app.module.ts:

```
    AwsSdkModule.forRootAsync({
      defaultServiceOptions: {
        useFactory: (cf: ConfigService) => {
          return {
            endpoint: cf.get<string>('S3_URL'),
            credentials: {
              accessKeyId: cf.get<string>('S3_ACCESS_KEY'),
              secretAccessKey: cf.get<string>('S3_SECRET_KEY',),
            },
          };
        },
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        inject: [ConfigService],
      },
    }),
```

and configure it as a provider like this:

```
    {
      provide: S3Lib,
      useValue: S3,
    },
```

where S3Lib is a constant

```
export const S3Lib = 'lib:S3-service';
```

Create a service for the methods and configure it as follows

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(S3Lib) private readonly _s3: S3,
  ) {}
```

and add the following function, which in theory should return the list of buckets

```
  listBuckets() {
    const response = this._s3.listBuckets((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('errors', err);
        return null;
      }
      console.log('data', data.Buckets);
      return data.Buckets;
    });
    return response;
  }
```

The controller for that function is

```
  @Get('/bucket/list')
  listBuckets() {
    return this.s3Service.listBuckets();
  }
```

but when requesting the bucket list, I get the following error

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

and in the console

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] this.serviceS3.listBuckets is not a function
```

- "nest-aws-sdk": "^3.0.1"
- "aws-sdk": "^2.1386.0"
- "@nestjs/cli": "^9.1.1"
- "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.2",
- "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.11",

Comment: Shouldn't you use @InjectAwsService(S3) in your service?

Comment: looks like `this.serviceS3` is not what you think it is. Check that out to see what's the value of `this.serviceS3`